# Removing duplicates using custom comparisons

Tags: python, python-3.x

The most convenient, "Pythonic" way to remove duplicates from a list is basically:

```
mylist = list(set(mylist))
```

But suppose your criteria for counting a duplicate depends on a particular member field of the objects contained in `mylist`.

Well, one solution is to just define `__eq__` and `__hash__` for the objects in `mylist`, and then the classic `list(set(mylist))` will work.

But sometimes you have requirements that call for a bit more flexibility.  It would be very convenient to be able to create on-the-fly lambdas to use custom comparison routines to identify duplicates in different ways.  Ideally, something like:

```
mylist = list(set(mylist, key = lambda x: x.firstname))
```

Of course, that doesn't actually work because the `set` constructor doesn't take a compare function, and `set` requires hashable keys as well.

So what's the closest way to achieve something like that, so that you can remove duplicates using arbitrary comparison functions?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use a dict instead of a set, where the dict's keys will be the unique values:

```
d = {x.firstname: x for x in mylist}
mylist = list(d.values())
```

Comment: That’s the generally easiest way to go with this. And performance should be almost equal to your set method.

Comment: Wow I've never seen the syntax `{x.firstname: x for x in mylist}` before. What's it called and where can I find it in the docs.

Comment: @MarwanAlsabbagh: It's a [dict comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/). It was added in Python 2.7 and 3.0. It's equivalent to `dict((x.firstname, x) for x in mylist)`.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
duplicates = set()
newlist = []
for item in mylist:
    if item.firstname not in duplicates:
        newlist.append(item)
        excludes.add(item.firstname)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have more flexibility with "in" operator

```
def is_in(value, value_list, comparer_function):
    """ checkes whether "value" already in "value_list" """
    for vi in value_list:
        if comparer_function(vi, value):
            return True
    return False

def make_unique_set(in_list, comparer_function=lambda a, b: a == b):
    """ retusn unique set of "in_list" """
    new_list = []
    for i in in_list:
        if not is_in(i, new_list, comparer_function):
            new_list.append(i)
    return new_list

make_unique_set(mylist, comparer_function=lambda a, b : a.firstname == b.firstname)
```